# Display days of the week with the date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display days of the week with the date like this

```
                       Fulltime    FulltimeTicket_Value Contract   Casual
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Saturday, 2018/06/09     1                  500           2           3
Thursday, 2018/06/07     2                 1000           1           4
Wednesday, 2018/06/06    0                    0           0           0
Friday, 2018/06/08       3                 1500           2           2
Tuesday, 2018/06/05      1                  500           4           1
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT  
    Date_to_Display = CAST(Time AS DATE),
    Fulltime = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'fulltime' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END),
    FulltimeTicket_Value = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'fulltime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) *
                                MAX(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'fulltime' THEN Vale ELSE 0 END),
    Contract = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'contract' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Casual = SUM(CASE WHEN jobtype = 'casual' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    CanLog AS clog
WHERE 
    Time >= '2018-02-12' AND time < '2018-02-15' 
GROUP BY 
    CAST(Time AS DATE)
ORDER BY 
    CAST(Time AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `datename()`:

```
select datename(weekday, time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, '2017/08/25') AS DatePartString;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.